# What does this regex validate for

Tags: regex

^([3,5][0-9]{7}|([a-zA-Z0-9]{4,6}))$

Comment: you wrote a regex and you don't know what it does? WIN!

Answer (score 0):

```
^([3,5][0-9]{7}|([a-zA-Z0-9]{4,6}))$
```

it's two part:

`[3,5][0-9]{7}`:strat with anyone in `3,5` ,end with 7 digits

`([a-zA-Z0-9]{4,6})`:4 to 6 digits or letters

`^`:start anchors     `$`: end anchors

Comment: [3,5] means one of any of the characters in that set.  Also, you might want to elaborate that there is a pipe so it is the first part OR the second part.  And that it has start and end anchors so that should match the entire string.

Comment: Thanks! I'm learning just wanted to throw myself into the deep end. What does strat do?